# Is it possible to retrieve the attributes of an Object I saved inside a .dat file in Java?

Tags: java, oop, object, fileoutputstream

I made this class, which has attributes 'Surname' and 'pc'

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
    String surname;
    int pc;

    Person(String a, int c){
        this.surname = a;
        this.pc = c;
    }
```

And created an instance of it called 'p'. I wrote the Object p inside the file below called 'people.dat', then read the file.

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        Person p = new Person(a, c);
        System.out.println(p.surname+" "+p.pc);

        FileOutputStream foo = new FileOutputStream("people.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(foo);
        oos.writeObject(p);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("people.dat");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object l = ois.readObject();
    }

}
```

My question is, is it possible to read 'p' 's attributes now that the object is written into a file? How could I access them if so?

Comment: Try casting `ois.readObject()` to be a `Person`.

Comment: Cast l object to person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `Object` to a `Person` to be able to access its members.  Instead of

```
Object l = ois.readObject();
```

try

```
Person l = (Person) ois.readObject();
```

Since the object being deserialized is, in fact, a `Person`, this will work without any issues.  Just be careful not to try to cast an object to the wrong type, unless you like `ClassCastException`s.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were very helpful.

Comment: If this has helped you, show a bit of appreciation, upvote and accept the answer as it can help others with the same problem